# How to cause creation of an EGL context?

Tags: android-ndk

I have an Android NDK application that is doing all of its rendering in software.
Now I want to use Open GL ES to do the rendering.

I've got unit tests running by calling EGL and creating a PBuffer.
Now I want to do everything in a window instead of a PBuffer.
I adapted the code from the hello-gl2 example.
I created a new java file that uses a GLSurfaceView instead of a SurfaceView.
I have created a few native functions for GLSurfaceView.
I have successfully called C from Java, and have successfully called Java from C.

Still, no pictures.

I traced through with Eclipse and got an error that says that GL calls are being made without having a current context. I am doing
    setEGLContextFactory(new ContextFactory());
    setEGLConfigChooser( translucent ? new ConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0) :
                                       new ConfigChooser(5, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0) );
    setRenderer(new Renderer());
However,
    ConfigChooser.chooseConfig()
never gets called. Who is supposed to call this? The sample code gives no clue.

Do I also need to make some change in an XML file?
Please give me some ideas of paths to pursue. I'm only running into dead ends.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there was a problem with threads: the GL rendering thread and the graphics database thread were deadlocking. Here is how I solved it. I reduced the number of threads by one, and managed GL myself:

1. derive MyGLSurfaceView from SurfaceView instead of GLSurfaceView.
2. When MyGLSurfaceView.surfaceCreated() is called, squirrel away the ANativeWindow (from the main thread) in a global.
3. initialize EGL in the database thread using the ANativeWindow to create an EGLContext.